# Edit Description field for users

Tags: date, powershell, active-directory

I’m trying to clean up my AD user accounts, in the past my organization would put a date in the beginning of the `Description` field for the users…

I can get all the text in `Description` field using PowerShell but I don’t know how to delete only the date in the “Description” field.

And the date in the field is written in the following formats: `mm/dd/yy` or `mm/dd/yyyy`

```
Get-ADUser -SearchBase $OU_To_Search -Filter {(description -like '*/*/* ^az') -and (enabled -eq $true)} -Properties cn,description | Export-csv C:\temp\A_Users.csv
```

I’m sure there is a better way of getting the date… but I’m not there yet.

Comment: Please clarify your question. Do you mean you don't know how to set (/overwrite) Description field? Do you know how to replace some text using -replace operator or .replace() methods? Do you know how to use Set-ADObject?

Comment: I'm trying to do the following in powershell:

Answer (score 0):

You could set the `Description` field to a variable and use the `-replace` parameter to remove the date like so:

```
$this = $this -replace "([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+) ",""
```

Then, it's just a matter of using `Set-ADUser` to replace the current description

Answer (score 0):

You can put your search, and then run your results through a -replace option and replace the regex filter of \d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{2,4}\s? (that's 1 or 2 numbers, followed by a slash, followed by 1 or 2 number, followed by a slash, followed by two through four numbers, and then if there's a space after it include that) and just leave off the item to replace it with so it simply removes it. Then output the updated result. Lastly I have it exporting to a CSV as you did above.

```
Get-ADUser -SearchBase $OU_To_Search -Filter {(description -like '*/*/* ^az') -and (enabled -eq $true)} -Properties cn,description|%{$_.Description -Replace "\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{2,4}\s?";$_}| Export-csv C:\temp\A_Users.csv
```

Alternatively you could have it `Set-ADUser $_` instead just outputting it to the pipe to be exported to CSV. To do that you would change `;$_}` to `;Set-ADUser $_}` and leave off the `|Export-CSV` bit at the end.